# Too many redirects - redirecting IE to a specific page with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect IE-user to a specific page by using htaccess. This is what I got so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Trident.*$
    RewriteRule (.*) /not-supported-browser.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But whenever I'm requesting some page with IE11, I'll get the error "too many redirects". I changed my condition to Firefox and Chrome, same behaviour so I think the condition is fine.

I'm using a CMS but this error also occurs when I'm deleting all CMS-specific rewrites in my htaccess.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get **too many redirects** because even after you redirect to `not-supported-browser.html` client browser remains same and first condition will still hold true.

You can use this rule to prevent this behavior:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Trident [NC]
RewriteRule !^not-supported-browser\.html$ /not-supported-browser.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Negative pattern `!^not-supported-browser\.html$` will skip redirecting if page is already `/not-supported-browser.html`.

Make sure to clear your browser cache when you test this change.